# how to reload current page without removing the url parameter using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a JSP page "tweet.jsp". This page's data is loaded on the basis of URL parameter, or after reading the URL parameter. Now what i want to do that on some process on that page i want to reload the whole page without removing the URL parameters. I am reloading because i need the new modified data from the database on that page with the same URL parameters.

Following is my URL

http://localhost:8080/TwitterClone/tweet.jsp?action=TWEET_REPLY&tweetid=15

Comment: Did you try `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: Thanks.. It's working